# Can child single post types have a different single-post_type template (Custom Post Types)?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Is it possible to assign different templates to child pages of post types?
The main purpose is to keep a clean URL but also differentiate the child pages from the parents (with the use of ACF).

Comment: You mean have more than one `single-post_type.php` for a single custom post type?

Comment: Specifically for child "posts" - I want the child posts to have a different template all together

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible, there are a lot of different possibilities how to achieve this.

First of all lets have a look on the WordPress template hierarchy which you really should understand:

[image: WordPress Template hierarchy]

As you can see there is a **single-$posttype.php** template (replace $posttype with your post type slug). This is what you should use to differentiate templates between post types.

If you want to differentiate templates **within the same posttype** I would recommend the following implementation within **single-$posttype.php**:

```
if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'template',true)=="templateA") {
get_template_part("templateA");
} else if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'template',true)=="templateB") {
get_template_part("templateB");
} else {
get_template_part("templateDefault");
}
```

Adjust this code to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I basically used conditions on the templates.